# jQuery is not a function in WordPress

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I got the error while I updated my WordPress theme. The WordPress jQuery file has enqueued as well and it's loading as well. Also notable that, I used the following function to avoid jQuery conflict on WordPress

```
(function($) {
    //Code 
})(jQuery);
```

The jQuery `$` sign is working as well but the 'jQuery' is not working. Here I attached a screenshot of the error.

[The Error Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7eBqq.png)

Comment: Chrome has it's own `$` variable. The fact that `jQuery` is undefined says to me that jQuery is not being loaded correctly or that it's being loaded after your code.

Comment: Wordpress uses jQuery in `noConflict` mode, please keep that in mind

Comment: I checked that the jQuery is loading at the top of all other js files.

Answer (score 0):

Change this block to:

```
$(function() {
    //Code 
})(jQuery);
```